# Paperclip multiple upload & save extra field

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, upload, paperclip

Im stuck uploading multiple photos to my model when adding an extra field to the photo model. In the code i hard code "1" value to the hidden_field, but i will change it eventually. The paperclip gem raises a rollback and won't insert the photos in the post. If i erase the "hidden_field" line it will success. Any ideas on how to add extra field to the upload in the view?

```
<%= form_for @campaign_point_of_sale, :html => {:multipart => true }, :url => "/pos/#{@point_of_sale.id}/post/#{@campaign.id}", :method => :post do |f| %>      
<%= f.hidden_field :id %>
    <label>Add photo <br />
        <%= f.fields_for :campaign_result_point_of_sale_photos do |builder| %>
        <% if builder.object.new_record? %>  
            <%= builder.hidden_field :is_mount_photo, :value => "1"  %>
            <%= builder.file_field :photo  %>
        <% end %>
        <% end %>
<%= f.submit(:value => "Save") %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it!
Just needed to delete the whole builder with both hidden_field and file_field, so the server would not try to insert a picture without an image file (just with a hidden_field value)

This can be achivied by surrounding both inputs with a div and deleting it (with jquery) at form submit if the file_field value was empty. Pretty cheap but works!